# Tmux powerline prompt command not found

Tags: tmux

I'm new to Vim.  I was experimenting with [vim-powerline](https://github.com/Lokaltog/vim-powerline) and tmux (and pathogen and vundle).

Somwehere in that process I tried to remove powerline and tmux started receiving this error.

My .tmux.conf file is empty.  How can I find where tmux is trying to run this command?

[image: powerline]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this problem, too, but not in the first tmux window.  It only happened for me in subsequent windows.  I found a solution, but not exactly the cause of the problem.

The short version is the set the value of the `POWERLINE_COMMAND` variable in your `.bashrc` on the line before you source the bash binding.  For me, that means:

```
export POWERLINE_COMMAND="$HOME/powerline/scripts/powerline"
. $HOME/powerline/powerline/bindings/bash/powerline.sh
```

I don't get exactly why this happens in subsequent tmux windows but I added some `echo` lines to the bash binding to find out what's happening.  When the binding is sourced in subsequent windows, `POWERLINE_COMMAND` is already set to `powerline`, so it skips the code that checks for the right place to set it.  I couldn't figure out where, how, or why it's already set, though.

Here's the code that does the check from the beginning of the bash binding:

```
if test -z "${POWERLINE_COMMAND}" ; then
    if which powerline-client &>/dev/null ; then
        export POWERLINE_COMMAND=powerline-client
    elif which powerline &>/dev/null ; then
        export POWERLINE_COMMAND=powerline
    else
        # `$0` is set to `-bash` when using SSH so that won't work
        export POWERLINE_COMMAND="$(dirname "$BASH_SOURCE")/../../../scripts/powerline"
    fi
fi
```

Since it works in the first window, I just set `POWERLINE_COMMAND` to point to the command that it points at in the first window.  Setting it before sourcing the bash binding skips the whole check.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to check your shell's configuration files. If you use e.g. use bash, check *$HOME/.{bashrc,profile}* or *$HOME/.zshrc* for zsh. There is probably a line like

```
. {repository_root}/powerline/bindings/bash/powerline.sh
```

according to the powerline [installation instructions](https://powerline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/overview.html#shell-prompts).